# cooking with a round based clay pot on an electric stove

Tags: slow-cooking, pot, gas, electric-stoves

I have a clay cooking pot,

similar to this one here

[image: clay cooking bowl]

and was wondering does anybody know of a heat diffuser I could use to cook with it over an electric Stove,

Its meant for a naked flame such as gas

but you know, Russia decide to invade Ukraine, so gas is becoming quite expensive.

Comment: How hot are you trying to get it?  And is the pot you’re using glazed?  Because if you’re stewing and it’s glazed so won’t absorb too much water, you might get away with putting it in a pot of water to diffuse,,, but if you had a pot, you could use that  directly if it’s just a matter of saving fuel

Comment: Welcome to SA!  Just to be clear ... the pot you have has a round bottom like that one?

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't recommend it.

You're going to be generating a large heat differential between top & bottom, even if you manage to find a heat 'spreader' capable of properly heating the entire lower half.
Heat differential & ceramics = cracking/or explosive shattering.

Comment: Some pottery vessels are designed for stovetop use.

Comment: @FuzzyChef - they would not be globe-shaped, for fairly obvious reasons. Testing Pyrex on a stove-top [by accident] would be enough to put you off for life. My mother did it once, my partner did it once. You find shards of 'glass' for months in odd corners of the house  ;) Also, the pot in the photo is absolutely beautiful, reminds me of some I got in Japan 25 years ago. I'd hate to test its expansion coefficient empirically.

Comment: Of course, stone-age man cooked in clay pots over an open fire for millennia, so it's not impossible. I just wouldn't like to test it on something expensive.

Comment: No particular reason to believe that it's expensive; OP said "like this one".

Comment: Pyrex isn't designed for stovetop use.  However, there are specific clay vessels that are, either made with earthenware or flameware.  So no, you can't put any random pot on the stove, but you can put a specific cooking pot on the stove if that's what it's designed for.